# How to expand a TableView Cell with a Accordion View inside it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Table view whose cells have a Accordion view. How to resize the tableview cell automatically when the Accordion view expands or collapses?

Hierarchy: UITableView -> UiTableViewCell -> Accordion View (Basically another table view)

**Note**: the number of elements in the accordion view varies.

Comment: library available in objective C https://github.com/genkernel/TreeView

Comment: Do we have a swift version of this?

Comment: Not exactly of this library but there are some other similar available for swift- I have not used these -- https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section

Comment: The problem is i have a tableview inside a cell, and the cells height should also increase with the inner tableviews expansion. Note that i cant use section headers because they are used to display some information.